# Unhandled exception at memory location in stitcher code opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, unhandled-exception, opencv-stitching

I am trying to debug the example for stitching images at [this](http://study.marearts.com/2013/11/opencv-stitching-example-stitcher-class.html) site.

Here is my complete code.

```
#include < stdio.h >  
#include < opencv2\opencv.hpp >  
#include < opencv2\stitching\stitcher.hpp >

#ifdef _DEBUG  
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core300d.lib")   
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc300d.lib")   //MAT processing  
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui300d.lib")  
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_stitching300d.lib")

#else  
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_core300.lib")  
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_imgproc300.lib")  
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_highgui300.lib")  
#pragma comment(lib, "opencv_stitching300.lib")
#endif  

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


void main()
{
    vector< Mat > vImg;
    Mat rImg;

    vImg.push_back(imread("./stitching_img/1.jpg"));
    vImg.push_back(imread("./stitching_img/2.jpg"));
    vImg.push_back(imread("./stitching_img/3.jpg"));
    vImg.push_back(imread("./stitching_img/4.jpg"));
    vImg.push_back(imread("./stitching_img/5.jpg"));
    vImg.push_back(imread("./stitching_img/6.jpg"));


    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault();


    unsigned long AAtime = 0, BBtime = 0; //check processing time
    AAtime = getTickCount(); //check processing time

    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(vImg, rImg);

    BBtime = getTickCount(); //check processing time 
    printf("%.2lf sec \n", (BBtime - AAtime) / getTickFrequency()); //check processing time

    if (Stitcher::OK == status)
        imshow("Stitching Result", rImg);
    else
        printf("Stitching fail.");

    waitKey(0);

}
```

However I am getting an error:

> First-chance exception at 0x00007FFFB36A8B9C in opencvtest1.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location
>   0x0000003F09CBD6B0. Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFB36A8B9C in
>   opencvtest1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory
>   location 0x0000003F09CBD6B0.

I searched for unhandled exceptions but every answer suggests specific solutions to those problems so couldn't figure out what is going wrong in my particular case.

Please help me figure out what is it that I am doing wrong in the code.

Comment: Did you check that all the files were properly loaded?

Comment: Are you sure the stitcher is returninig OK and the output Mat is valid? Replace your if with: if(Stitcher::OK == status && rImg.empty() == false).

Comment: I changed the if statement to the one you mentioned. I got the same error. @Sergio

Comment: @JoachimPileborg How do I check that? The program is is building fine. But when I debug using Local Windows Debugger, I get this error.

Comment: Check what the `imread` calls return, do they succeed and return a valid `Mat` object?

Comment: Add a try / catch block to your code, it might help figuring out the problem. Do: try { /* all your code in main */ } catch(const cv::Exception &cv){ printf("Opencv exception: %s", cv.msg.c_str()); } catch(...) { printf("Unknown error"); }

Comment: Yes, your program is syntactically and semantically correct, which is what the compiler checks. But what happens at ***run-time*** if one or more of the files can't be found? The compiler can't check for that, you have to add checks in the code (if-statements) that are executed at run-time to make sure that they don't fail.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Visual Studio? If so, you can activate the debugger to stop the moment when an exception will be thrown. Menu Bar -> Debugging -> Exceptions -> C++ Exceptions -> std::exception : activate checkbox.

Comment: @Sergio I am getting     Error:Assertion failed <ssize.area<> > 0> in cv::resize, file C:\builds\master_PackSlave-win64-vc12-shared\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\imgwrap.cpp, line 3208

Comment: I just ran that code in my machine an it worked. I'm on ubuntu 14.04, with opencv 2.4.10. I got the images from that site, except the image 4 (i couldn't find it there).

Comment: Ohh.. I am running on Windows 8.1 64 bit OS OpenCV 3.0.0. Is that an issue? I read at some site that openCV 3.0.0 version has some bugs running a few programs. Is it because of the version I am using?

Comment: And now in the output box, these are the messages.  

`First-chance exception at 0x00007FFFB36A8B9C in opencvtest1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000C33053D320.

First-chance exception at 0x00007FFFA276512D (msvcp120d.dll) in opencvtest1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFA276512D (msvcp120d.dll) in opencvtest1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.`

Comment: It can be an Opencv bug. I was upgrading my version to Opencv 3.0, but some machine learning features were not working, then I gave up and stayed with 2.4.10. Did you tried the opencv forum?

Comment: Your images have all the same size? What is the size? And, can you link you program with opencv version 2.x?

Comment: Yes. It is working with opencv 2.4.10 now. Thank you :) Yes, all images have the same size. 854X480