# Alternate unhandled exceptions in visual studio

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, unhandled-exception

I am trying to build a stitcher code using opencv n visual studio. I asked a question about unhandled exception [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433746/unhandled-exception-at-memory-location-in-stitcher-code-opencv) but then it worked fine in Opencv2.4.10 It builds fine now and also debugs well once, twice or maximum three times. After that it starts throwing unhandled exceptions at memory locations. Then, if I clean and build the solution, it again works fine once or twice but then again throws unhandled exceptions.

My question is what is the root cause of these exceptions? And also is there a way to ensure that there are no such exceptions at all?

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions can have many causes, but for novice programmers they are usually programming errors of one sort or another.

There are more ways to go wrong than there are to go right, so I can't give a general cause of all exceptions.

To discover the root cause of each exception, run the program in the debugger, with "break on exception thrown" option set. Then, whenever an exception is thrown, you can examine the code, and the call stack, to discover why the exception is thrown.